# Arguments for basemap drawmeridions?

Tags: matplotlib-basemap

Is there a way to specify the thickness and color of meridians and parallels in matplotlib-basemap? specifically drawmeridians() and drawparallels()

The documentation is hard to find.

```
m = Basemap(projection='ortho',lat_0=90,lon_0=0)
x, y = m(lon,lat)
m.drawmapboundary(zorder=0)
m.drawparallels(np.arange(0.,90.,15.))
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0.,360.,60.), labels=[True,True,True,True])
m.scatter(x,y,3,marker='o',color=str(colors[i]), zorder=1)
```

Right now the output is a thick solid black line, however I am looking for a thinner dark gray segmented line.

Answer (score 1):

Use `linewidth`, `dashes`, and `color` parameters:

```
m.drawparallels(np.arange(0.,90.,15.), linewidth=0.25, \
                dashes=[12, 10], \
                color='k')
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0.,360.,60.), labels=[True,True,True,True], \
                dashes=[7, 15], \
                linewidth=0.3, color='g')
```